# Приведение char к int

Tags: c

Как я могу привести char  к int для проведения арифметических операций с числом, которое хранится в виде символа/массива символов?

```c
int a = 1;
float b = 2;
char c = "3"; //char c может быть равно 43 или любому другому числу
int d = a+b+c;
```

Comment: Символ заключается в одинарные кавычки. Т.е: `char c = '3'`

Comment: Если важно, что в `char` код *цифры*, то не забудьте проверить эту переменную функцией [isdigit()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit)

Comment: *"char c может быть равно 43 или любому другому числу"* - не может. Если имеется в виду значение кода символа - то от 0 до 255, если имеется в виду строке, типа "345" - то это уже не `char`, а массив `char`ов...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ сделать это для unsigned int -

```
char num = '1';
int newVal = (int)num - (int)'0';
```

Еще один вариант :

```
char num = '6';
int newVal = num - 48;
```

Ну или самый верный вариант использовать atoi :

```
int val;
char str[20];   
strcpy(str, "98993489");
val = atoi(str);
```

Ну а дальше делайте с числом что хотите

Comment: `char num = '10';` - сомнительно.

Comment: Писал не думая)

Comment: Второй вариант не будет работать с EBCDIC.